# User Control BringToFront() Event?

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I want to refresh a datagridview on my User Control, I call the user control with a BringToFront(); action on my main form, is there any event so I can refresh the datagridview once the User control is set to front? something like:

**Custom Control:** (Has datagridview: dgvCustomers)

```
namespace Healthcare
{
    public partial class Overview : UserControl
    {
        public Overview()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void RefreshGrid()
        {
            using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                customersBindingSource.DataSource = db.Customers.ToList();
            }
        }

        private void Overview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main form:**

```
private void btnOverview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ccOverview.BringToFront();
    txtTitle.Text = "Healthcare - Overview";
    RefreshGrid(); // Does not exist in the current context
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easier to just group these 2 methods together. Its simple its evident, its easily maintainable and you don't have to plumb up other events to do magic things

**Example**

```
public void RefreshMyAwesomeGrid()
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        customersBindingSource.DataSource = db.Customers.ToList();
    }
}

...

MyUserControl.BringToFront();
RefreshMyAwesomeGrid();
```

**Update**

> The thing is that I can not acces the datagrid from my main form, on
>   my main form I have a button and once that button is pressed it brings
>   the user control to front so I have to put the datagridview refresh
>   action in the User Control but I want to trigger it with a main form
>   action

Assuming your DataGrid is in your userControl... Unfortunately `BringToFront` cant be overridden. However, you have a couple of options.

The simplest, would be just put a public method on your `UserControl` class `RefreshMyAwesomeGrid`. when you call `BringToFront` call `RefreshMyAwesomeGrid`

Either that, or just make your `OwnBringToFrontPlusRefresh` <-- seems a bit meh though

Or you could use decoupled messages depending on if you are using any frameworks

**Update 2**

Just dig in to your user control

```
private void btnOverview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ccOverview.BringToFront();
    txtTitle.Text = "Healthcare - Overview";
    ccOverview.RefreshGrid(); // exists now
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I can not acces the datagrid from my main form, on my main form I have a button and once that button is pressed it brings the user control to front so I have to put the datagridview refresh action in the User Control but I want to trigger it with a main form action

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however when I try to call RefreshMyAwesomeGrid(); on my main form, it says that it does not exists in the current context

Comment: @Dan can you update your question for everyone else playing at home, with the exact layout and structure of your form, as its a little confusing, i mean what holds what, where does the DataGrid live where does the usercontrol live, what does the main form hold

Comment: Thank you, looks very simple after all

Answer (score 1):

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    button1_MouseClick()
    {
        ucr1.BringToFront();
        ucr1.Focus(); // 포커스를 해줘야만 Enter 이벤트가 발동한다. 중요하다.

    }
}

class ucr1 : Usercontrol
{
    private void ucr1_Enter(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```